# find x values (randomly generated) that gives certain y values

Tags: matlab

I've found some guidance on how to find x values corresponding to y values on plots, but I'm dealing with something slightly different.
Below is the code for what I've been trying to do:

```
a = 1 + (2-1).*rand(1,10);
b = 5 + (10-5).*rand(1,10);
c = linspace(0, 100, 10);
y = (c-a)./b
x = linspace(0, 10, 10);
scatter(x,y,'b.')
idx = (5 <= y & y <= 10);
hold on, plot(x(idx), y(idx), 'r.')
hold off
```

So my `y` values (coming from `a` and `b`) are random, and I want to find what range of `a` and `b` will give me 5 < `y` < 10.  I introduced `x` to visualize possible ranges of `y` values so trying to find range of `x` that gives certain range of `y` wouldn't be useful for me. Would there be an easier way to approach this problem? Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As you know `find(y >= 5 && y <= 10)` find the indexes which you expect. In this way, if you find indexes of y, you can apply these for `a` and `b`. As value of each element of `y` is defined exactly by the respective equivalent index in `a`, `b` and `c`, so you found the related index of `a` and `b` to get the specified range in `y`.